# How to send multiple user location from seperate devices to one particular user

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app where the user can see available merchants nearby. I am not getting how can i fetch all merchants location and populate it on user map in android.

Answer (score 0):

- You can use database for storing location,pre-define lat-long, fetch them and put marker on map

Comment: Will it be good enough to send the data to server and fetch them from ther e continuosly

Comment: yup... it will work. just that u need to run your service in background also.. so to get continuous lat-long